# Navigate Stack Exchange site switcher with keyboard

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, accessibility, stack-exchange-button

After I type a few characters into the Stack Exchange site search, I usually try to navigate with the down-arrow to the site I'm looking for. Of course that doesn't work, forcing me to relocate to the mouse.

Could the arrow keys navigate the search results to improve convenience, speed and accessibility (similar to Spotlight in OS X)?

[image: Stack Exchange Multicollider SuperDropdown™]

Answer (score 4):

The arrow keys <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> *scroll* this site list.

The <kbd>Tab</kbd> key can be used to focus the next site, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the previous.

Comment: The tab focus is a native part of browsers moving from link to link, but the arrow keys don't work for me. Perhaps thats a browser side implementation. My thought was that a key event listener could catch the arrows while in the input, and focus up or down the results.

Comment: @MichaelJasper: Not sure I follow you. When you type something which gives many results (like nothing, or "and"), and then leave the input field (i.e., with tab), pressing the arrow down key should scroll this list down. AFAIK this is default browser behaviour.

Comment: I agree with @unor: once you typed something in the search box, you can use tab (and Shift-Tab) to navigate in the list and it is a default behaviour, implemented in all modern for a long time now... Arrows should be used only for scrolling on standard webpage.

Comment: The [ARIA-recommended behaviour for a widget](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/usage#managingfocus) is that tab enters or exits the widget and arrows navigate inside it.  This is the behaviour of a simple drop-down list (HTML form element) in most browsers.  The only time this is a problem is if changing focus triggers extensive changes, which isn't the case (you need to explicitly activate the link).  Furthermore, even the tab order is messed up; after opening the dropdown list, all the entries in the list end up in the tab order *before* the header, so you have to work through them backwards.